# How can I fix a SPOJ time limit exceeded error on the STAMPS challenge?

Tags: c++, performance

Here is the link for the problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/STAMPS/;
here is the ideone link for the current code: http://ideone.com/AcHfc6;
here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int t,x,n,sum,sum2,count,i,j;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(j=1;j<=t;j++)
    {
        cin>>x>>n;
        sum=0;
        int offer[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>offer[i];
            sum+=offer[i];
            sort(offer,offer+n);
        }

        if(sum>=x)
        {
            sum2=0;
            count=0;
            for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                sum2+=offer[i];
                if(sum2<=x)
                    count++;
                else
                    break;
            }
            cout<<"Scenario #"<<j<<":"<<endl;
            cout<<count<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Scenario #"<<j<<":"<<endl;
            cout<<"impossible"<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code gives the right answers for the given test cases but it causes TLE.  I've tried converting my `cin`'s and `cout`'s to `scanf`/`printf` but, weirdly enough, the answers were not the same and I don't know how the answers were different from each other.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your main problem is here:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>offer[i];
    sum+=offer[i];
    sort(offer,offer+n);
}
```

You sort the data for every number that's entered.  Also, you sort random data because you only have `i` rows of valid data in the array, not `n` rows. The sort should be done once, outside the loop:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>offer[i];
    sum+=offer[i];
}
sort(offer,offer+n);
```

Comment: here is the code after i did that,http://ideone.com/oLsWyR
it suddenly gave a wrong answer for the test cases,i don't know why :/

Comment: I don't know why, either; I didn't look at whether the rest of your logic was correct.  However, it looks to me as though your algorithm is greedy, and never does any backtracking.  There might be other solutions than just the first one that works that use fewer elements, even after sorting.  I've not sat down to work out a scenario, but are you sure that being greedy always gives you the smallest number of items?  (It doesn't — counter-example: `100 8: 80 35 35 35 5 5 5 5`. The shortest solution is 35+35+35 for 3 items; the greedy code finds 80+5+5+5+5 for 5 items.)

Comment: I see,well i can try a different approach but i really want to know what's wrong with the code here,i think the TLE can be fixed by converting cout and cin to printf and scanf but when i tried that it gave the wrong answer,as illogical as that might sound.

Comment: You wanted to know why your code was too slow. It was because if you get 1,000 friends, you'll be sorting an array of 1,000 elements 1,000 times, putting random data into it, and taking a long time to do so. Now you are wanting to know why your answers are incorrect too; that is a different problem. Your answers were correct previously by happenstance — bad luck, if you will. They should have been wrong; apparently, they weren't. I've outlined one of the non-timing problems with your code; you don't produce a minimal answer for a valid set of input values. The rest of the problem is yours.